# Kemal caching responses with handler middleware

Tags: http, caching, crystal-lang, kemal

#### Kemal caching responses with handler middleware

I'm trying to do caching of some GET request with Kemal.

```
class CachingHandler < Kemal::Handler

    property cache : Hash(String, IO::Memory)

    def initialize
        @cache = Hash(String, IO::Memory).new
    end

    def call(context)
        puts "Caching"
        puts "Key: #{ context.request.resource }"
        if output = @cache[context.request.resource]?
            puts "Cache: true"
            IO.copy output, context.response.output
        else
            puts "Cache: false"
            puts "Cache: building"
            context.response.output          =
            @cache[context.request.resource] = IO::Memory.new
            # continue
            puts "Cache: continue"
            call_next context
        end
    end
end
```

But in the first request the browser it's always waiting a response. And in the second request send a "Closed stream (IO::Error)" error.

Comment: Output IO [is closed](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/e2a1389e8165fb097c785524337d7bb7b550a086/src/http/server/request_processor.cr#L53) after each request. Next time you are trying to read from that IO, you get "Closed stream (IO::Error)"

Answer (score 2):

You're indirectly setting `context.response.output` to `IO::Memory.new`. So, the next handler won't write to the connection's output stream but to the memory IO.

You'll need to copy the stream data to both memory *and* socket. Maybe a `IO::MultiWriter` can help with that, like `response.output = IO::MultiWriter.new(response.output, memory_io)`.

Additionally, I'd recommend not to store `IO::Memory` instances but rather their raw data as `Bytes` (`io.to_slice`). Once you put it in the cache, there's no point in having an IO anymore. You can just write bytes directly to the output stream when the cache is hit (`response.write(bytes`).